# Copying an object from one NSMutable array to another

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have done a bit of searching and not really found an answer to my question.
The code below is trying to copy the contents of a NSMutable array that contains some objects.

I have tried the code below however when run there is no error, but the new arrays do not get the objects as I would have thought they would.

csvContent is a array that contains objects from parsing a CSV file and the other NSMutable arrays round1, round2 etc have been defined in the header file.

The NSLOG output is correct but the arrays contain no objects.

```
for(int loopNumber = 0; loopNumber < [csvContent count]; loopNumber++)
{
    if ([[[csvContent objectAtIndex:loopNumber] objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        [round1 addObject:[csvContent objectAtIndex:loopNumber]];
        NSLog(@"round 1");
    }

    if ([[[csvContent objectAtIndex:loopNumber] objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        [round2 addObject:[csvContent objectAtIndex:loopNumber]];
        NSLog(@"round 2");
    }

    if ([[[csvContent objectAtIndex:loopNumber] objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"3"])
    {
        [round3 addObject:[csvContent objectAtIndex:loopNumber]];
        NSLog(@"round 3");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually create and initialize the arrays for `round1`, `round2`, and `round3`? In other words, make sure they are not `nil` when this loop is run.

Also, your code is terribly inefficient. You call `[csvContent objectAtIndex:loopNumber]` six times inside the loop. Try this (I'm using `i` instead of `loopNumber` to save typing):

```
for (int i = 0; i < csvContent.count; i++) {
    NSArray *loopContent = csvContent[i];
    NSString *val = loopContent[1];

    if ([val isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [round1 addObject:loopObject];
    } else if ([val isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        [round2 addObject:loopObject];
    } else if ([val isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        [round3 addObject:loopObject];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy, you were right I had not created and initialised the arrays first :(

Thanks also for the code optimisation :)